# Python - assign increasing class to list val based on mean

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have the following problem:
having a list of values, let's say:

```
x = [1000, 950, 860, 1120, 430, 270, 0, 15, 0, 26, 278, 0, 950, 1020, 980, 1040, 670, 540, 820, 0, 0, 0, 190, 270, 479, 1247]
```

I calculate the mean val:

```
mean = np.mean(x)
# 505.96
```

Now I would like to calculate a list, where a value is assigned (starting from 1) to each item of list x, that if the item is higher than mean, then it assigns one (same) value until the relation its shifted (lower than mean), then it assigns the second val, and so on. So for the example x list, the output is as follows:

```
x = [1000, 950, 860, 1120, 430, 270, 0, 15, 0, 26, 278, 0, 950, 1020, 980, 1040, 670, 540, 820, 0, 0, 0, 190, 270, 479, 1247]
#   [1,    1,   1,   1,    2,   2,   2, 2,  2, 2,  2,   2, 3,   3,    3,   3,    3,   3,   3,   4, 4, 4, 4,   4,   4,   5   ]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take [`np.diff`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) on the result of the comparisson with the mean to see when the "shifts" occur. Then take the [`np.cumsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) to increment the values:

```
np.cumsum(np.diff(x>mean, prepend=False))
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4,
       4, 4, 4, 5], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You can try in this way apart from the another answer:

```
mean = np.mean(x)
out = []
if out[0]>mean:
    cur  = 'high' 
app = 1
for i in x:
    if i>mean and cur=='high' or (i<mean and cur=='low') :
        out.append(app)
    elif i<mean and cur=='high':
        cur = 'low'
        app += 1
        out.append(app)
    elif i>mean and cur=='low':
        cur = 'high'
        app += 1
        out.append(app)
print(out)
```

Comment: I just tried a solution even though the first answer is fast and not complex